# Ajax calls with SetInterval

Tags: php, jquery, setinterval

I'm working on a website that manages live auctions. All the bids are recorded in a database and I need that users can see immediately when another user makes a new bid.

I'm thinking to use jquery-ajax to launch a php script every 500 milliseconds, through setTimeout().

I'm not preatty sure if this solution is affordable, because the large amount of ajax calls (120 per minute).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't query the database. Setup a RSS/JSON feed that updates continuously alongside the database (with a fixed window size of let's say a second). Query the JSON object instead, as it'll be lighter on both you and your client.

Comment: Most ajax calls take longer than 500 milliseconds, so even setting `setTimout()` to 500 milliseconds will not result in half-second updates, but rather, a new update will be requested a half-second after the last response was received and processed.

Comment: You should look at this kind of solution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) rather than intensive ajax calls (sorry the link is broken here due to the missing closing ")", you need to add it manually)

Comment: You would take a look at NodeJs too...

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your server, you could set up a script that writes a json file that your ajax call can get.  This way multiple users will still only access a single file.  A static page will be less server intensive than constant calls on the db.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggetions.

Comment: @ darma, I have already heard about COMET, but I'm little afraid about  the compatibility with the oldest browsers. Are you sure that it could work well?